# How do I list files modified on or before particular date?

Tags: linux, file-search

Using linux commands , is there way to list files which are created an hour (or particular date) before ?.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can use the `find` command along with `-mmin` and `-mtime` flags.
For example to list *.txt files in Downloads folder modified more than 30 days ago use this:

```
find $HOME/Downloads -name  '*.txt' -mtime +30
```

`+` implies  more than

Comment: Valid answer, but a note to Original Question: this depends on the file metadata stored with on the filesystem. This can be reset by the `touch` command. In short, **you can never know 100% when it was changed**.

Comment: @Rich. Thanks for sharing the note. I agree. In my reqs, I wanted to cleanup iso files built doing last compliations. it takes so much space. So, I wanted to cleanup everytime after successful completion of build.

Answer (score 1):

The `find` command's `-mmin` and `-mtime` predicates can select files based on their mtime.